# Bootstrap element not rendering without hard reload

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

So I'm trying to use the bootstrap-select component from here - https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/, while using bootstrap version 5.0.2 in a plain html file, every time the webpage loads, I have to hard reload (ctrl + shift + r) for the select component to render.

I'm using cdn to include the botstrap, the css includes are -

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

and the js includes are -

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

and lastly, this a snippet from my js file where I'm creating multiple selects for the header of a table (based on the number of columns, defined by userDropdown) -

```
const createTableHeaders = function() {
    table = document.getElementById('my-table');

    var thead = document.createElement('thead');
    thead.setAttribute('id', 'my-header');

    theadRow = document.createElement('tr');
    theadRow.classList.add('table-header')
    
    table.appendChild(thead);
    thead.appendChild(theadRow);

    for (var j = 0; j < userDropdown.length; j++) {
        th = document.createElement('th');
        theadRow.appendChild(th);

        sel = document.createElement('select');
        sel.classList.add('selectpicker', 'w-100', '.text-danger', 'select-menu');

        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = 'default option';
        option.setAttribute('disabled', '');
        option.setAttribute('selected', '');
        sel.add(option)
        th.appendChild(sel);
    }
}
```

I'm really confused as to why this is happening, cant move forward since i need them to render as and when theyre created through the js script. Can someone please point out what I could be doing wrong/how i could resolve this?

Comment: You are using both bootstrap 4 and 5. Pick one. Also, why not simply use this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/forms/select/

Comment: I've exclusively used v5 except for the select component, which I really need. Is there anyway i can use one component from v4 with the rest being v5? I tried making local files with the css and js from 
1. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css and
2. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

but still had the problem persist. Any recommendations?

Comment: No, you have to pick one. Or you open both unminimized in an editor and try your hand at manually combining them. Good luck, you'll need it!

Comment: Also, cant use the link you provided cause i need multi select and thats only available in v4, ie the one im using